# How to perform bitwise OR operation between two rows in same SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bitwise-operators

I have an SQL table with a structure similar to the following:

```
  Name     Value
(varchar)  (bit)
__________________
 Val1       1
 Val2       1
 Val3       0
 Val4       0
 Val1       0
 Val2       0
 Val3       0
 Val4       1
```

So basically, I have two instances of the same row but with a different bit value. I want to retrieve distinct rows from this table, with the bit value being OR'ed. So for the given example, the result would look like:

```
Name    Value
```

---

```
Val1      1    (1 | 0)
Val2      1    (1 | 0)
Val3      0    (0 | 0)
Val4      1    (0 | 1)
```

Can this be achieved?
I am working in Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Any kind of help is appreciated. Please do let me know if any further clarification is required.

Comment: Is value of data type `bit`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Observing that "bitwise OR" has the same function as the aggregate function `MAX` (assuming all inputs are either 0 or 1, if any input is 1, the result is 1, otherwise 0) and accounting for the fact that we can't directly aggregate `bit`, this seems to work:

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(17) not null,Value bit not null)
insert into @t(Name,Value) values
('Val1',1),
('Val2',1),
('Val3',0),
('Val4',0),
('Val1',0),
('Val2',0),
('Val3',0),
('Val4',1)

select Name,CONVERT(bit,MAX(CONVERT(int,Value))) as Value
from @t group by Name
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank You so much brother!

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever you just taught me something today. Thanks

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever: Any ideas on how to handle the same in case the data type is an INT and not a bit? In this case taking MAX would not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, hoping that value is numeric field with values 0 and 1.

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Value)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: This is why I asked for clarification on the data types. Despite much documentation for SQL Server claiming (reasonably correctly) that `bit` is a numeric type, unfortunately you're not allowed to use it with `MAX`.

Comment: It is a bit. In the solution that Damien provided, he has converted it to an int. Makes more sense to me now. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Value BIT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @t (Name, Value)
VALUES
    ('Val1', 1), ('Val2', 1), ('Val3', 0), ('Val4', 0),
    ('Val1', 0), ('Val2', 0), ('Val3', 0), ('Val4', 1)

SELECT Name, MAX(Value % 2)
FROM @t
GROUP BY Name
```

output -

```
---------- -----------
Val1       1
Val2       1
Val3       0
Val4       1
```